# How to use Gatling in a Scala 3 project

Tags: scala, sbt, gatling, scala-3

I want to use Gatling in my **Scala 3 / sbt** Project.

The problem is that Gatling packages its library without Version-Postfix. So I think you have the same problem for any Scala library that does that.

I tried a few things, for example:

- Adding the dependency according to the documentation:

  ```
  libraryDependencies += "io.gatling" % "gatling-test-framework" % "3.7.2" % "test"
  ```
- Gives:

  ```
  Modules were resolved with conflicting cross-version suffixes in ProjectRef(uri("file:.../"), "api"):
  com.softwaremill.quicklens:quicklens _3, _2.13
  ```

And

- According to the Scala 3 Documentation:

  ```
  libraryDependencies += ("io.gatling" % "gatling-test-framework" % "3.7.2" % "test").cross(CrossVersion.for3Use2_13)
  ```
- Gives:

  ```
  not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/gatling/gatling-test-framework_2.13/3.7.2/gatling-test-framework_2.13-3.7.2.pom
  ```

Is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why but *gatling-test-framework* is not published with the version postfix as you said.

This means that you don't need/can't use the `for3Use2_13` as there is no 2.13 version nor 3 version: there's just a single version without postfix.

Looking at its dependencies, version 3.7.2 targets Scala 2.13: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.gatling/gatling-test-framework/3.7.2. As Scala 3 is compatible with Scala 2.13, it should be just fine with your first attempt.

Not sure where the conflict with *quicklens* comes from but if it comes from Gatling dependency, you can probably exclude the `_2.13` version from Gatling (or even globally) as you are pulling the `_3` version yourself:

```
libraryDependencies += "io.gatling" % "gatling-test-framework" % "3.7.2" % "test" exclude("com.softwaremill.quicklens" % "quicklens")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - unfortunately that did not help still `com.softwaremill.quicklens:quicklens _3, _2.13`

Comment: I might have made a typo on the exclusion, double check the documentation. Also did you run `dependencyTree` to see where both dependencies are coming?

Comment: I had a direct dependency to quicklens - removing it did the trick - but still it should be a way to resolve this problem.

Comment: Finally I could exclude Quicklens from Gatling - but sadly Gatling stopped working - so no quicklens in my project;(.

Comment: `exclude("com.softwaremill.quicklens" % "quicklens")` should be `exclude("com.softwaremill.quicklens", "quicklens")` (comma not percent)